# adding nio files copy progress bar

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, progress-bar

I was wondering if there was a way to update a progress bar that uses NIO library's Files.copy, it's being used to download a file in a worker thread. code below.

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try (InputStream in = download.openStream()){
                        Files.copy(in, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("file download");
                    }
                }
            });

            Platform.runLater(
                    () -> view.enableButton()
            );
            return null;
        }
    };
```

there's a progressbar that I've tried binding to the task, but all that seems to do is cause a bug and immediately re-enable the download button.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `updateProgress(current_progress, max);` inside your `call()` method to update progress

Also bind your `Task` to progressbar properly

```
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();
```

Comment: Since it's only a single call to files.copy, where/how would I get the current progress? I've seen other ways of downloading a file using a loop with a progress bar but this solution seemed simplest, just not if I wanted to show the progress of the download, which is why I checked here if there was something I may have missed.

Comment: @msd94 To get progress, you may have to  use `FileInputStream.read()` and `FileOutputStream.write()` instead single call to `Files.copy`